# Class array property by reference

Tags: php

If I have the following variable in a class

```
protected $address
```

and in a function `test`, I do

```
$testAddress = $this->address;
```

and then

```
$testAddress['state'] = 'KO';
```

Does that change the state for `$this->address` ... meaning any function that uses `$this->address` will have the modified state?

Comment: No it does not. $this->address will remain the same unless you pass by reference

Comment: Would have been pretty easy to write that code and see what happens.

Comment: The fact that you need it means that you have fundamental issues with design

Answer (score 0):

It will only change the state or value of $testAddress but not $this->address.

As per the given code, nothing yet has been set as value on $address